# sublime-2 "sftp command line executable could not be found"

Tags: sublimetext2, google-cloud-platform

trying to setup sublime SFTP to work on google cloud (GCP) VM and keep getting this basic error.
I think my sublime-2 setup is messed up, but I am not sure how to solve it.
this is my sftp setup file as for now -

```
{
    // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "sftp",

    "sync_down_on_open": true,
    "sync_same_age": true,

    "host": "[SERVER_IP]",
    "user": "[MY_USER]",
    //"password": "password",
    //"port": "22",

    "remote_path": "/home/[MY_USER]/",
    "connect_timeout": 30,
    "ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/my-ssh-key",

}
```

Comment: Does executing `which sftp` in a terminal tell you where `sftp` is located (e.g. `/usr/bin/sftp`)?

Comment: yes it says: /usr/bin/sftp